# What is the purpose of separating RouteSpecification from Cargo

Tags: domain-driven-design

Looking at the ddd sample application, I cannot figure out why the `Cargo` [Cargo.java](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/cargo/Cargo.java) object needs to have a separate reference to a `RouteSpecification`.

Wouldn't it be simpler to have `origin, destination and arrivalDeadline` part of cargo class and skip this RouteSpecification class altogether and expose methods such as `updateDestination` and `satisfiedByItinerary`

RouteSpecification is used to validate if an itinerary can satisfy the cargo route or not etc. But I don't see any reason why such a task cannot be handled by the Cargo class itself, What's the point of this separation?

```
public class Cargo implements Entity<Cargo> {

  ...
  private Location origin;
  private Location destination;
  private Date arrivalDeadline;
  ...
```

Comment: one "word": Single responsibility principle

Comment: It's about being faithful to the Ubiquitous Language. It's about creating highly cohesive meaningful wholes that have a single responsibility. It's about making the implicit explicit. It's just OO done right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a documentation walk, there's a useful pointer in the [version 1 introduction](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/index.html).

> One of the most requested aids to coming up to speed on DDD has been a running example application. Starting from a simple set of functions and a model based on the cargo example used in Eric Evans' book

Given this, we can reasonably assume that the design had similar motivations to those in chapter 7 of [the blue book](http://a.co/0pTH8UZ).

> Delivery Specification defines a delivery goal, which at a minimum would include a destination and an arrival data, but it can be more complex.  This class follows the specification pattern.
>
> This responsibility could have been taken on by the Cargo object, but the abstraction of Delivery Specification gives at least three advantages.
>
> 1. Without Delivery Specification, the cargo object would be responsible for the detailed meaning of all those attributes and associations for specifying the delivery goal.  This would clutter up Cardo and make it harder to change.
> 2. This abstraction makes it easy and safe to suppress detail when explaining the model as a whole.  For example, there could be other criteria encapsulated in the Delivery Specification, but a diagram at this level of detail would not have to expose it.  The diagram is telling the reader that there is a specification of delivery, and the details of that are not important to think about (and, in fact, could be easily changed later).
> 3. This model is more expressive.  Adding Delivery Specification says explicitly that the exact means of delivery of the Cargo is undetermined, but that it must accomplish the goal set out in the Delivery Specification.

```
But then why isn't origin a part of RouteSpecification?
```

I haven't gone digging through the whole project history, but my guess is that `Cargo.origin` and `RouteSpecification.origin` aren't actually interchangeable.  (origin is part of the RouteSpecification, but the RouteSpecification can change over time).

From the [version one javadoc](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/dddsample/code/trunk/dddsample/tracking/core/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/tracking/core/domain/model/cargo/Cargo.java)

> A cargo can be re-routed during transport, on demand of the customer, in which case a new route is specified for the cargo and a new route is requested.
>
> It may also happen that a cargo is accidentally misrouted, which should notify the proper personnel and also trigger a re-routing procedure.

The version one code also indicates that cargo can be *misdirected* (which is not the same as misrouted).

If you look carefully at the [different](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/dddsample/code/trunk/dddsample/tracking/core/src/test/java/se/citerus/dddsample/tracking/core/domain/scenario/CargoLifecycle.java) [scenarios](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/test/java/se/citerus/dddsample/scenario/CargoLifecycleScenarioTest.java), you'll see that they handle misdirection in different ways; the newer version does so by replacing the route specification and then searching for a matching itinerary.

Answer (score 1):

If you considered the consequences of completely refactoring out the RouteSpecification class from the solution, you would find that `origin`, `destination` and `arrivalDeadline` seem to get passed around together much of the time. This is a strong sign that the values are closely related. "Cohesion" is a principle of object oriented programming in which closely related concepts are located close together in code, so to follow this principle, you can bring these three concepts together in a single class.

Many programmers would agree that it is simpler to pass around a single RouteSpecification object everywhere these values are used rather than `origin`, `destination` and `arrivalDeadline` separately.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, But then why isn't `origin` a part of `RouteSpecification`? Why is that attached to the Cargo object separately ?